# Why does booting from a 64 bit Win 8 USB install work on a 32 bit laptop?

Tags: 32-bit, windows-installation, windows-8-upgrade

I upgraded a 64 bit Windows 7 laptop to Windows 8 through the Upgrade Assistant, creating a bootable USB without any problems. I installed it successfully. Before I purchased an upgrade for my 32 bit Windows 7 laptop, I decided to boot from the USB with the 64 bit ISO to see what happened. The Windows 8 install screen came up with all the options. Should it not have detected that the laptop is 32 bit and therefore the install should have given an error?

I cancelled the install before it did anything, but now I want to know if I need to download the iso again after purchasing the upgrade on my 32 bit laptop? I've read the answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/497872/is-windows-8-pro-upgrade-32-bit-or-64-bit), which confirms what is said in [this article](http://www.zdnet.com/the-ultimate-windows-8-upgrade-faq-7000006815/) - a 32 **or** 64 bit iso will be downloaded depending on the hardware of the computer you are upgrading. If that is the case, then why did it boot into the install screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't personally tried this, but I believe from rumors that the x64 installer will launch on a 32 bit system, but I don't think it will let you do anything. Unless it is really a 64bit processor - then it will let you install/upgrade.

So to have a complete answer - the legal/legit versions of Windows do not have 32 bit/64 bit on the same media. I have heard of illegal/non-legit versions floating where they combined both (supposedly via a boot option) - of course I would never advise downloading such copies but that information is just here for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

That just means the boot up is not 64 bits and is shared. I've had this when I've inserted the wrong dvd and I boot then start the upgrade. Only to be told a moment later it's the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

> Should it not have detected that the laptop is 32 bit and therefore
>   the install should have given an error?

Why would it?  If you proceeded through the installation it would have wiped the 32-bit operating system.

> I cancelled the install before it did anything, but now I want to know
>   if I need to download the iso again after purchasing the upgrade on my
>   32 bit laptop?

If you want to upgrade your 32-bit Windows 7 installation you will need to download the x86 iso.  The license key can be used for either installation.

Comment: ok, it's just having a capped Internet connection is a nightmare.

Comment: @Arabella - I don't know where you live but there are many alternatives to whatever internet connection you have. Clear comes to mind. You could ask that question on here :).